# Cocoapods v. 1.10.0 ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES error Xcode Version 12.0.1

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I want to use [this custom alert](https://cocoapods.org/pods/PMAlertController) I found in the CocoaPods library. But when I install the library via pod install command the terminal says:

```
[!] The `OurTeamTests [Debug]` target overrides the `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-OurTeamTests/Pods-OurTeamTests.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `OurTeamTests [Release]` target overrides the `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-OurTeamTests/Pods-OurTeamTests.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `OurTeamUITests [Debug]` target overrides the `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-OurTeamUITests/Pods-OurTeamUITests.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `OurTeamUITests [Release]` target overrides the `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-OurTeamUITests/Pods-OurTeamUITests.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.
```

I found this [link](https://www.devsbedevin.net/cocoapods-always-embed-swift-standard-libraries/) to overtire setting from Pods file. But not it terminal still throw the errors I listed above.

Here is my Pods file:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '14.0'

target 'OurTeam' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for OurTeam
    pod 'Parse'
    pod 'PMAlertController'
  target 'OurTeamTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  pod 'Parse'
  pod 'PMAlertController'
  end

  target 'OurTeamUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  pod 'Parse'
  pod 'PMAlertController'
  end

end


post_install do |installer_representation|
    installer_representation.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES'] = 'YES'
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: I found a solution from this link https://programmersought.com/article/56217292468/

Comment: 1) On Xcode go to Targets->Build Settings->Combined(All) search for ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES, 
2) select the option, press the delete key of the computer to immediately return to normal mode. 

When you do this the text "Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries" will change from bold to normal